# How to avoid 2019 MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR on getting Topic.Name

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

The following is used when

```
int topicOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
MQTopic mqTopic = qmgr.AccessTopic(mqCloneSpecs.topicString, "", 
    MQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_PUBLICATION, topicOptions);
```

The above part of the program builds a list of QueueManagers and a list of Topics which are used to call a listener class in a Windows service.

```
int tLoopCounter = 0;
foreach (MQTopic topic in topicOut)
{
    tLoopCounter++;
    // NOTE: We blow up here with 2019 MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR if we access the property topic.Name 
    //Console.WriteLine("Loop through topics topic.IsOpen: " + topic.IsOpen); 
    //Console.WriteLine(" OpenOptions:" + topic.OpenOptions); 
    debugLocation = "4053";
    Console.WriteLine(" OpenStatus=" + topic.OpenStatus);


    debugLocation = "4054";
    i = tLoopCounter - 1;
    Console.WriteLine("i=" + i);
    debugQueueInfo = " topicPut #" + tLoopCounter + " QueueMgr:" + queueManagerForTopicsOut[i].Name.TrimEnd();

    // currently getting 2019 : MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR on the line below 
    debugLocation = "4055";
    debugQueueInfo += "Topic:" + topic.Name; 
    Console.WriteLine("Pump:Topic.Put:" + debugLocation + ":" + debugQueueInfo);

    debugLocation = "4057";
    topic.Put(mqMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Pump:Topic.Put completed"); 

}
```

When I try to add the Inquire option, as shown here:

```
int topicOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;
```

then I die with this error:

> DebugLocation=Q3012 Exception: System.ApplicationException:
>   MQException in Acce ssQueue ---> IBM.WMQ.MQException:
>   MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR

Also, the OpenStatus=True from the Console.WriteLIne at debugLocation=4053. My first thought that if it were closed, that would cause this error.

Comment: What is the value of each of these `MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING` where you declare the result type as `int`?
Where is the value of `i` being declared does it need to be incremented in the loop as well?`queueManagerForTopicsOut[i].Name.TrimEnd();` this line definitely maks ZERO Sense` show where you are declaring `i`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: DJ - Obviously I couldn't post my entire program, so I tried to focus on the issue.  The var i is just a subscript to get the name of the QueueManager from a List.  The Topic is coming from the foreach loop. The get queueManager name works, the getTopic name does not (that's why I separated them onto two different lines to prove exactly what was causing the issue).  In another part of my code, I deal with queues as well, and getting the Queue name is working.

Comment: I too get the same error. Looks like a defect. Worth speaking to IBM.